# Unable to read memory on kernel32.dll base address

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making some research and currently i need to get base address of the KERNEL32.dll.

What i already done:

```
// get PEB structure
PPEB peb = (PPEB)__readfsdword(0x30);

// get ldr linked list and go to kernel32 module
PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY ldrDataTableEntry = (PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)peb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink->Flink->Flink;

// get DllBase address from LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY
HMODULE kernel32 = (HMODULE)ldrDataTableEntry->DllBase;
```

Unfortunately I can't read memory on this address. Here is my screenshot from VS while debugging:
[image]

Can someone explain me how it works? Am I doing something wrong? Maybe some references.

Comment: Do you mean the preferred load address stored in the PE metadata, or do you mean the base address of the DLL in an extant process?

Comment: Is what you're trying above different from `(pvoid)GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll")`?

Comment: No, but i am trying to understand how it works internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY ldrDataTableEntry = (PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)peb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink->Flink->Flink;
```

The `InMemoryOrderModuleList` is not the first member of the `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` structure, so you need to use the `CONTAINING_RECORD` macro to get the correct `ldrDataTableEntry` value.

```
PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY ldrDataTableEntry = CONTAINING_RECORD(peb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink->Flink->Flink, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
```

Now you can access the `DllBase` address:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was not obvious for me. For anyone who doesn't understand why we should use CONTAINING_RECORD macros, look at it definition.

This line should also work:
PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY newnewldrDataTableEntry = (PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)((PCHAR)(peb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink->Flink->Flink) - (ULONG_PTR)(&((LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY*)0)->InMemoryOrderLinks));